# Complexes $K$, $L$, imply $|K| \cap |L|$ is polyhedron.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am using Armstrong's topology text, and have been really stumped on what this question is asking. It says

> If $K$ and $L$ are complexes in $\mathbb{E}^n$, show that $|K| \cap |L|$ is a polyhedron.

The reason I am confused about this statement is that the following picture yields a counter example, doesn't it? [image]

I am struggling with this question because of this example. Maybe it is just wrong... Or maybe the language should phrase it otherwise?

EDIT: Also, *technically* this question comes before the barycentric subdivision and compact surfaces sections, so I would assume that I can't use any sort of "every compact surface admits a triangulation" argument.

Comment: The picture does not demonstrate a counter example - the darker shaded area is easily seen to be the underlying set of a simplicial complex (and thus a 'polyhedron')

Comment: @user259242 How is that? Wouldn't there be $4$ points which would place them out of general position, resulting a no smallest $k$-simplex?

Comment: I'm not sure what the source of your confusion is, but this might help: a square is a polyhedron since, for example, it is the underlying space of the simplicial complex formed by 'adding' the diagonal of the square. Now, the darker shaded area in the picture is clearly homeomorphic to a square. Thus it is homeomorphic to the underlying space of a simplicial complex. This is my definition of a polyhedron.

Comment: @user259242 Then, maybe Armstrong didn't give the best explanation. I get the 'adding' the diagonal part, but that was where my edit came in; I feel like the 'adding' argument would make the  assumption that we can triangulate these compact subsets.

Comment: (X is a polyhedron) <=> (X can be triangulated)

Comment: @user259242 Okay. That would be a game changer; there is no explicitly statement of this (or seemingly) equivalent definition in my text. Thank you very much.

Comment: The fact that the two are equivalent follows from the definitions. A space is a polyhedron if it is homemomorphic to the underlying space of a simplicial complex. A triangulation of a space X is a simplicial complex whose underlying space is homeomorphic to X

Comment: @user259242 Thank you very much. :)